# QuickBooks web php sdk DataService returns null

Tags: php, sdk, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am trying to read entities from QuickBooks but im getting NULL from DataService.

I am testing on my localhost (LAMP),

I created the Accounting App, and SandBox.

I downloaded SDK version 2.2.0 for PHP from here https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0500_developer_kits/0209_php/php_sdk_for_quickbooks_v3

I changed the baseURI to sandbox in SDK_ROOT/sdk.conf

```
<baseUrl qbd="https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/" 
                qbo="https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/" 
                ipp="https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/" />
```

I get the oauth token and store it in session,

PHP:

```
$token = unserialize($_SESSION['token']);
$requestValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(
                $token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret'], 
                OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, 
                OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET
);
$realmId = $_SESSION['realmId'];

$serviceType = $_SESSION['dataSource'];
$serviceContext = new ServiceContext($realmId, $serviceType, $requestValidator);

$dataService = new DataService($serviceContext);
$startPosition = 1;
$maxResults = 100;
$allEntities = $dataService->FindAll('Customer', $startPosition, $maxResults);
```

$allEntities is always NULL.

When I try to save i get:

```
 CheckNullResponseAndThrowException - Response Null or Empty thrown

$customer = new IPPCustomer();
$customer->DisplayName = "NewOne123";
$dataService->add($customer);
```

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**:
In class `SyncRestHandler` when i print out the response from (line:~269)

```
$this->GetOAuthResponseHeaders($oauth)
```

I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2015-10-09T02:29:24.520-07:00">
<Fault type="SystemFault">
<Error code="10000" element="SystemFailureError">
<Message>An application error has occurred while processing your request</Message>
<Detail>System Failure Error: java.lang.NullPointerException</Detail></Error></Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but the solution to the non-functional SDK is https://packagist.org/packages/activecollab/qbo-wrapper